# Child theme stylesheet not reflecting the changes

Tags: child-theme

I have created a child theme and the website is showing up properly with the activated child theme. I made some changes in the child theme's php files for adding two controls in the child theme's Appearance --> Customize section which will add a button ("Download my cv" button) on the home page. To do this I have added two php files and made modifications in them, keeping the same folder structure as the parent theme. They are working perfectly locally but not on the server. Although in localhost I have made the changes directly on the parent theme files.

I also can see the child theme's style sheet is loading by view source but on making modification in the style sheet its not showing the changes. Whereas any modification in functions.php is working. Some help would be appreciated. Please check the screenshots. Thanks
[image: changes in localhost on parent theme working fine but changes in the child theme on server not working]

Comment: Hi @Pushku in a child theme the functions.php file is loaded in _addition_ to the functions.php file of the parent theme. All other php-files overwrite their counterpart in the parent theme. So if you want to add two extra controls, I would suggest just adding them in the child theme's functions.php file. If you really want to load one or two extra php files, you can add an `include()` function in the child functions.php with the correct path to the additional files. How do you currently load those two PHP files? Can you give us that code? Thanks!

Comment: “All other php-files overwrite their counterpart in the parent theme” This isn’t true. Only certain template files can be replaced, or files included with `get_theme_file_path()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for adding that. I didn't know that. What template files cannot be replaced? My answer was based on [this section](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#adding-template-files) in the Codex, but that probably isn't actual anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.I copied one file from inc-->customizer folder which is creating the controls with $wp_customize->add_setting and $wp_customize->add_control.This file also has the following code in the beginning, $default = career_portfolio_get_default_theme_options(); which is defined in default.php.The following code is in the default.php: $defaults['intro_button_title']= esc_html__( 'Download My Cv','career-portfolio');
$defaults['intro_button_url']= ''; Not sure why the child theme files are not working. @JacobPeattie I didn't see any files with get_theme_file_path().

Comment: @ralphsmit I am new to this. Can you please explain where exactly can I add the include () function ? Here is my functions.php code:    <?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
?>

Comment: I finally found the solution. I created a separate php file in inc>Customizer folder and wrote a function with $wp_customize->add_setting() and $wp_customize->add_control() for creating the controls. Then I am calling the function from function.php file llike so, require get_stylesheet_directory() . ‘/inc/customizer/abt_customizer.php’;